# Delete all demo data

Tags: templates, database, features

Many templates come with demonstration data that may be installed to show off the features of a template. Is there a simple method of deleting all this data or am I going to be forced to delete each item individually?

Comment: no simple method of deleting - but you could just install without the demo data.

Comment: Templates themselves don't come with sample data. You've most likely installed the quickstart package which includes the entire Joomla CMS **and** the template. When installing the quickstart package, you have the choice to install sample data. Simply uncheck it ;)

Comment: Just to clarify, the content is already on the site. It includes articles, categories, etc. It would be nice if there was some way to just wipe all of it out and be able to start fresh without having to reinstall the whole CMS from scratch. But then again I suppose a 'button' with that ability would be rather dangerous!

Comment: Are you trying to remove articles including its category only, or you want to remove other things such as modules, plugins and settings those come with template installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to 
1) Content->Articles, Check All and Trash.
2) Content->Categories, Check All and Trash.
Voila: all content in Trash. Then you can Empty trash.

Comment: you also need to delete some modules and menu items.

Comment: and contacts, and banners, and newfeeds, and tags